# How do I update my Eclipse project to include "spring-boot-start-security-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, build-dependencies

I built a project that included several dependencies.  So far so good.  However, I now need a new dependency called "spring-boot-start-security-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar".  I noticed that all of the spring-boot-start-* are located in "Project and External Dependencies".  I found "spring-boot-start-security-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar" in Maven Central and downloaded it.  I discovered I cannot load it into "Project and External Dependencies".  I created a .lib folder in my project and moved the .jar into the folder.  I right clicked on the project and continued properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jars... and clicked on the .jar in my lib folder.  It loaded but eclipse is barking about several imports associated with the .jar cannot be resolved.  I can add the "spring-boot-..." to my Gradle dependencies and it will build correctly using gradle build in the command line.  It's just that now Eclipse is barking about several dependencies that cannot be resolved.  Is there someway of adding a new dependency to my project without having to start over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this dependency in pom.xml under dependencies tag. Adding a jar will not add it in classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using gradle and included the dependancy in my gradle.build file.  It builds correctly when using gradle to build the project.  The problem is that Eclipse does not have the .jar installed and shows a bunch of errors.  My question is -- How can I include a new spring boot dependancy jar in my eclipse project?  I can build the project all day long using gradle with no issues.  How do I install the .jar so Eclipse stops barking about not finding jars?

Comment: I have not worked closely with gradle, but for maven eclipse creates a Maven dependency Libraries which has all the jar it refers. I assume some similar concept is used for Gradle too. Check your project with the libraries  it is referring too. You can check it through Project Properties -> Java Build Path

Comment: Hello user1211, I think you definitely were going in the right direction.  My issue was how to get Eclipse to use Gradle to download and load the jars into the correct Gradle classpath.  I figured it out just when you were typing in your comment.

Comment: You need to setup eclipse with gradle, there are various references online. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593321/starting-with-gradle or http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html should help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out how to get the dependencies into Eclipse with Gradle.  Just to be clear, I wanted to add a new Spring Boot Dependency to my eclipse project after I had already created the project -- "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.4.1.RELEASE".  The issue, of course, is eclipse does not have the correct jars installed.  Any reference to those jars causes eclipse to flag the import jar statements "cannot be resolved".  I added "compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.4.1.RELEASE') in the gradle.build dependencies.  By the way, I got the correct Gradle dependency statement from maven central. If I build with Gradle, the project builds properly with all of the correct jars installed.  However, and this is my problem, Eclipse does not have the jars and continues to bark about not being to resolve the jar -- very irritating.  The build has the jars but Eclipse does not.  To get the dependency jars into Eclipse do the following;

```
 1. Add the dependency into gradle.build shown below and save it.
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.4.1.RELEASE')

 2. Right Click on the Project > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project
```

Gradle then uses the gradle.build dependencies and correctly loads the jar into the project's classpath.  No more Eclipse barking!

Comment: Just to let everyone know.  I gave the answer credit to "user1211".  His comment got me pointed in the right direction.  My answer above is how you actually do it.  Use my answer to get the dependencies loaded into the eclipse project.